# why do i get an error on bcrypt compare? async/await function

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await, bcrypt

I'm trying to log a user with nodeJs and MySql

Here my function to connect a User:

```
export async function connectUser(email, password, cb) {

  console.log('Entry connectuser');
  let db = dbConnect();

  await db.query('SELECT id, email, password FROM user WHERE email = ?', [email], async (error, result) => {
    if (error) return cb(error);

    const user = result[0];
    
    console.log(result);
    console.log(user.email);
    console.log(user.password);
    console.log(user.id);
    
    const isValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (isValid === true) {
      const token = jwt.sign({id: user.id, email: user.email }, secret, {expiresIn: 86400 });
      return cb(null, token);
    }
    
    return cb(new Error('Invalid Credentials'));
    
});
```

I get this error: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Illegal arguments: object, string" on the bcrypt.compare()

I suppose that it's an error of async/await but i can't fix it... some ideas?

Comment: make sure `password` is a string not object

Comment: yes it's a string, typeof(user.password) returns me "string"

Comment: what does `typeof(password)` return

Comment: oh yes, my mistake was in my controller, i forget to put the password in paramaters... ^^' thank you

Comment: Just [don't pass a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72729569/1048572) when you want to get back a promise to `await`

Comment: (Same problem with `db.query` btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [doc](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js), you should use bcrypt.compare like that:

```
    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user.password, function(err, res) {
  if (err){
    // handle error
  }
  if (res)
    // Send JWT
  } else {
    // response is OutgoingMessage object that server response http request
    return response.json({success: false, message: 'passwords do not match'});
  }
});
```