# With async the bcrypt.hash function returns undefined but it works fine with .then

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, bcrypt

Here is the code with async (returns `undefined`)

```js
userService.register = (username, password) => {
  return bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, async(err, hash) => {
    const newUser = new user({
      username: username,
      password: hash
    })
    return await newUser.save()
  })
}
```

and this is the same code with `.then`, it works correctly

```js
userService.register = (username, password) => {
  return bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds)
    .then(hash => {
      const newUser = new user({
        username: username,
        password: hash
      })
      return newUser.save()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is documented behaviour:

> [Async methods that accept a callback, return a Promise when **callback is not specified** if Promise support is available](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#with-promises)

You're passing a callback in your first example, so `bcrypt` doesn't return a promise.

Another way to write your code is to make the wrapping function `async`:

```
userService.register = async (username, password) => {
  const hash    = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);
  const newUser = new user({
    username: username,
    password: hash
  })
  return await newUser.save(); // or just `return newUser.save()`
}
```